# Orthogonality on complex inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be a complex inner product space. I need to show the following:
$(x\ and \ y\ are\  orthogonal)\ \Rightarrow (\left \| \lambda x+\beta y \right \|^{2}=\left | \lambda  \right |^{2}\left \| x \right \|^{2}+\left | \beta  \right |^{2}\left \| y \right \|^{2})$ for all $x,y$ in $V$ and for all $\lambda$, and $\beta$ in $\mathbb{C}$

If $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, then $\left \langle x,y \right \rangle=0$.Then $\left \| \lambda x+\beta y \right \|^{2}=\left \langle\lambda x+\beta y,\lambda x+\beta y  \right \rangle=\left | \lambda  \right |^{2}\left \| x \right \|^{2}+\left | \beta  \right |^{2}\left \| y\right \|^{2}+\lambda \beta ^{*}\left \langle x,y \right \rangle+\lambda ^{*}\beta \left \langle x,y \right \rangle^{*}=\left | \lambda  \right |^{2}\left \| x \right \|^{2}+\left | \beta  \right |^{2}\left \| y \right \|^{2}$)

By $*$ above $\lambda$, I mean complex conjuguate.

However, to prove the other direction, all what I can say is that Re($\lambda \beta ^{*}\left \langle x,y \right \rangle$)=$0$. Anyone knows how to continue from here to prove $\left \langle x,y \right \rangle=0$

Comment: Take different choices of $\lambda$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lambda=\beta=1$ then ${\rm Re}(\lambda\bar\beta\langle x,y\rangle)=0$ means ${\rm Re}(\langle x,y\rangle)=0$, and for $\lambda=i,\,\beta=1$ it means ${\rm Im}(\langle x,y\rangle)=0$.

Anyway, for the direction $\Leftarrow$, one usually uses only that the original condition holds with $\lambda=1$ and $\beta\in\{1,i,-1,-i\}$. (See also *polarization identity*.)